# Should Vector3 inherit from Vector2?

Tags: c++, architecture

I'm creating a couple of classes `Vector2` (X & Y) and `Vector3` (X, Y & Z), but I don't know whether to make `Vector3` inherit from `Vector2`, or whether to re-implement the member variables `m_x` and `m_y` again? What are the pros and cons of each side (inheritance vs redefinition).

**Edit:** I'm using C++ (VS2010).

Comment: Why don't write a general vector class for n dimensional vectors and then (if needed) inherit a vector2 and a vector3 class. You may also use templates for the general class and inherit versions for integer vectors and float vectors, too. Edit: Why don't you use a optimized math library?

Comment: you could do that, but it's kind of silly. Most functions would not be applicable. Also it could cause some problems if you feed a function requiring Vector2 and Vector3. Things would be much simpler if you just copied the shared code and made them separate.

Comment: By no stretch of the imagination "Vector3 is a Vector2", they could both inherit from a parent VectorN though

Comment: Having a `VectorN` could sound like a good idea but it's not the one chosen in today's game engines: too much unneeded complication (e.g. *lots* of different method signatures). You'll probably never need more than `Vector2`, `Vector3` and `Vector4`. Though for C++, I wonder if C++11 could help in this matter.

Comment: Well, they could be derived from `Vector<N>`.

Comment: Yeah, but then you'll probably need a virtual table and that's one of the cases where the runtime & memory costs can matter. Ideally, a `Vector3` should be just 3 `floats` as far as the memory is concerned. Not saying that's impossible, just that I've never seen that in a production engine.

Comment: As an aside, do you think a Vector should always contain floats? As I've templated it right now so it can have any type.

Comment: Yes, I do think so. Until as long as you don't need anything else that `floats`. You know, YAGNI, KISS, all that stuff. `Vector2`, `Vector3` and `Vector4` with no inheritance and `floats` only is really the de facto standard in game engines.

Comment: @MarkIngram You should `#define real float`, and use `real` everywhere in the program.  This way it's easy to switch between `double` and `float` if you need to.

Comment: I hope you meant `typedef float real;` ;).

Comment: @bobobobo: ... or just use Vector2<class T = float> { T x; T y; ... } and Vector3<class T = float> { T x; T y; T z; ... } to allow for different storage types.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou: Why would you need a virtual table?? There is no reason for Vector<N> to be polymorphic.

Comment: @Samaursa If you *derive* from `Vector<N>` as suggested by @avakar, then you'll need a virtual destructor. I've no idea why you would do that instead of *specializing* it but this is overcomplication all the way down anyway.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou No, you will need the virtual destructor _only_ if you are trying to `delete` a derived `Vector<N>` class by the base class pointer. That is, you are designing your `Vector<N>` class to be polymorphic, which I have never seen in any engine. `Vector<N>` base class is quite common however. You can easily protect against deletion by base class pointer by having a protected `dtor` (and probably a protected `ctor`) in the base class. It is actually quite advantageous to have all the common functionality in the base `Vector<N>` class.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou: :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No it shouldn't. The only thing you'd be using from the inheritance is the `x` and `y` components. The methods used in a `Vector2` class wouldn't be useful in a `Vector3` class, they would likely take different arguments and perform operations on a different number of member variables.

Comment: +1, I should pay more attention to the popup so I don't write redundant stuff.

Comment: [Classical inheritance overuse](http://corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/The_Pain_of_Inheritance).  A `Vector3` IS-NOT-A `Vector2` (so it should not inherit), but an `Apple` IS-A `Fruit` (so it may inherit).  If you twist your mind enough, a `Vector3` HAS-A `Vector2` in it, but the performance loss and difficulty coding means you will write completely separate classes for `Vector3` and `Vector2`.

Comment: But you could (an in my opinion should) write a n-dimensional vector class to inherit a 2d vector and a 3d vector from that.

Answer (score 8):

There's a curious thing you can do with C++ (You didn't specify a language, and this answer is mostly because I think it's nice to see alternatives, though I don't really believe this is useful in most cases.)

Using templates you can do something like this:

```
template <class T, class S, int U>
class VectorN
{
    protected:
        int _vec[U];
    public:
        S& operator+=(const S c)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < U; i++)
            {
                _vec[i] += c.at(i);
            }
            return (S&)*this;
        }
        int at(int n) const
        {
            return _vec[n];
        }
};

template <class T>
class Vec2 : public VectorN<T,Vec2<T>,2>
{
    public:
        T& x;
        T& y;
        Vec2(T a, T b) : x(this->_vec[0]), y(this->_vec[1])
        {
            this->_vec[0] = a;
            this->_vec[1] = b;
        }
};

template <class T>
class Vec3 : public VectorN<T,Vec3<T>,3>
{
    public:
        T& x;
        T& y;
        T& z;
        Vec3(T a, T b, T c) : x(this->_vec[0]), y(this->_vec[1]), z(this->_vec[2])
        {
            this->_vec[0] = a;
            this->_vec[1] = b;
            this->_vec[2] = c;
        }
};
```

and this can be used like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Vec2<int> v1(5,0);
    Vec2<int> v2(10,1);

    std::cout<<((v1+=v2)+=v2).x;
    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, I don't think this is useful, and it will probably complicate your life when you try to implement dot/normalize/other stuff and try to be generic with any number of vectors.

Comment: Yeah, all the genericness seems nice, only most of the time you only need a standard 3-vector with 3 floating point components -- all the angle brackets will make `Vector3f v` quite a bit more bloaty `Vector3<float> v`

Comment: @bobobobo Yes, I agree. My vector classes are usually vec2 and vec3 with no parent, but still make them templates. If writing Vector3<float> bothers you, you can always typedef it

Comment: ..And now the C programmer's argument.. "but what about increased compile time for using templates??"  Is it really worth it in this case?

Comment: @bobobobo I never had any problem with my compile times :P, but I never worked on a project that compile time would be an issue. One could argue that the compile times justify not using floats when you need integers.

Comment: @bobobobo With explicit instantiations and not including your inline file in the header, compile times will be no different. Additionally, the template angle bracket _bloat_ is just one `typedef` away.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of speed, the first question you should ask yourself when doing *any* inheritance is if you're going to be using them polymorphically.  More specifically, is there any situation where you can see yourself using a `Vector3` as if it were a `Vector2` (which, by inheriting from it, you're explicitly saying that a Vector3 "is-a" Vector2).

If not, then you shouldn't use inheritance.  You shouldn't be using inheritance to share code. That's what components and external functions are for, not that you'd be sharing any code between them anyway.

That being said, you might want easy ways to *convert* `Vector3`s to `Vector2`s, and in that case you can write an operator overload that will implicitly truncate the `Vector3` to a `Vector2`.  But you shouldn't inherit.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's highlighted the problem, I was looking at this from a "code sharing" point of view (i.e. not having to "re-type" the X & Y values).

Comment: +1 great answer, there's no polymorphic use between vectors of different sizes.

Comment: This is the biggest thing I was going to add to my own answer - +1 for sure. (Although there are strange circumstances in which I _can_ imagine wanting polymorphism - e.g., 2.5d 'heightmap' games where things like distance checks, pathing etc. will canonically want to be done in 2d but you still need to provide 3d coordinates for objects)

Comment: @LukeB. Although in OPs case I agree that it seems there is no reason to inherit from `Vector2` but inheriting from a base `Vector<N>`? That makes perfect sense. Moreover, why does inheritance automatically mean polymorphic behaviour? One of the best things about C++ is that you can have zero cost inheritance. No need to add _any_ virtual methods (including virtual destructors) in the base `Vector<N>` class.

Answer (score 5):

No, since every method will need to be overridden as well you will have no use of actually inheriting from it.

If something, they could both implement a Vector interface. However, since you probably don't want to add/sub/dot/dst between a Vector2 and Vector3 this will have unwanted side effects. And having different parameters etc. would be a hassle.
So I really cannot see any pros of inheritance/interface in this case.

An example is the Libgdx framework, where [Vector2](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java) and [Vector3](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.java) have nothing to do with each other, other than having same type of methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use SIMD [arrays](http://sci.tuomastonteri.fi/programming/sse) are likely the best. If you still wish to use operator overloading you can consider using an interface/mixin to access the underlying array - for example, here is a starting point that has only the (untested) `Add`.

Notice how I haven't provided `X`/`Y`/`Z`, each `VectorX` class would inherit directly from this one - for the same reasons specified by other people. Still, I have seen arrays used as vectors many times in the wild.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(void)
    {
        Values = AllocArray();
    }

    virtual ~Vector(void) 
    { 
        _aligned_free(Values);
    }

    // Gets a pointer to the array that contains the vector.
    float* GetVector()
    {
        return Values;
    }

    // Gets the number of dimensions contained by the vector.
    virtual char GetDimensions() = 0;

    // An example of how the Vector2 Add would look.
    Vector2 operator+ (const Vector2& other)
    {
        return Vector2(Add(other.Values));
    }

protected:
    Vector(float* values)
    {
        // Assume it was created correctly.
        Values = values;
    }

    // The array of values in the vector.
    float* Values;

    // Adds another vector to this one (this + other)
    float* Add(float* other)
    {
        float* r = AllocArray();

#if SSE
        __m128 pv1 = _mm_load_ps(Values);
        __m128 pv2 = _mm_load_ps(other);
        __m128 pvr = _mm_load_ps(r);

        pvr = _mm_add_ps(pv1, pv2);
        _mm_store_ps(r, pvr);

#else
        char dims = GetDimensions();
        for(char i = 0; i < dims; i++)
            r[i] = Values[i] + other[i];
#endif

        return r;
    }

private:

    float* AllocArray()
    {
        // SSE float arrays need to be 16-byte aligned.
        return (float*) _aligned_malloc(GetDimensions() * sizeof(float), 16);
    }
};
```

*Disclaimer:* My C++ might suck, it's been a while since I used it.

Comment: __Wait man__, does your use of `_aligned_malloc` mean the [bug I opened](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767382/error-c2719-defaultvalue-formal-parameter-with-declspec-align-32-wont-be-aligned) isn't really a bug?

Comment: You shouldn't use pointer casts to get your values into the `__m128` register, you should use [`_mm_loadu_ps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1b16s7z(VS.80).aspx) instead. A good sample class is [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) under "vectorclass.zip"

Comment: @bobobobo I'll make a best-attempt at an edit - take special heed to the disclaimer ;).

Comment: @bobobobo `_mm_loadu_ps` should work out for you with that struct (where `_mm_load_ps` won't). I also added your suggestion - feel free to edit the question if you feel that I am barking up the wrong tree (it has been a while since I have used C[++]).

Answer (score 1):

Another serious con to having Vec3 inherit from Vec2 or, arguably, to having both inherit from a single Vector class: your code will be doing a *lot* of operations on vectors, often in time-critical situations, and it's very much in your best interests to make sure that all of those operations are as fast as they can be - much more so than it is for many other objects that aren't quite so universal or low-level.  While a good compiler will do its best to flatten out any inheritance overhead, you're still relying more on the compiler there than you'd like to; instead, I would build them as structs with as little overhead as possible and possibly even try and make most of the functions that use them (with the exception of things like operator+ which can't really be helped) be globals rather than methods on the struct.  Early optimization is generally recommended against, and with excellent reason, but in a circumstance like this where you can be sure that vector operations will almost certainly be a substantial chunk of your runtime, it's worth a bit of effort up front to design for efficiency.

Comment: -1 because: class and struct only have access grant implications in C++ and the OP didn't specify a language anyhow, non-virtual member functions have the same performance implications as non-member functions, and virtual member functions (which do potentially exhibit the issues you're concerned about) only exist if you make them, not simply by utilizing inheritance.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Valid points on all fronts; I tend to 'default' to C/C++ and so saw the question through that lens.  I _do_ believe there are legitimate performance (as well as conceptual) reasons for not going the inheritance route, mind you, but I could have been much better on the specific details.  I'll try and revisit this and see if I can give a better accounting.